# PHP form submit with categories

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a contact script where once someone has filled out information it will send it to my database. Anyways it all works fine other then choosing the category. What the categories does is it checks in the database for category names and then it comes up with them in a list when someone is contacting me. This works, although when submitting everything goes into my database other then the categories.

```
 <?php
  if($_POST[add]){
    $title = strip_tags($_POST['title']);
    $category = $POST['category'];
    if(!$title){
        echo 'All fields are required!';
    }else{

    $sql = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `posts` (`title`, `category`) VALUES ('$title', '$category')");
    $sql->execute();
    $q = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if($sql){
            echo 'Published successfully';
        }else{
            echo '<strong>Error:</strong> '.mysql_error();
        }
    }
}else{
    echo '
    <form method="post">
            <label for="title">Title:</label>
            <input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="" size="50" maxlength="40">

        <br>
        <br>

        <label for="category">Category:</label><br>
        <select name="category" style="width:200px;">';


        $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts_categories ORDER BY `id` ASC";
        $stm = $dbh->prepare($sql);
        $stm->execute();
        $users = $stm->fetchAll();
        foreach ($users as $row) {
        echo '<option value="'. $row["title"] .'">'. $row["title"] .'</option>';
        }
        echo'

        </select>

            <input type="submit" name="add" value="Add"> <input type="reset" value="Reset">

    </form>';
}

?>
```

Comment: What else is exactly going into the database?

Comment: @CosLu Just that for now. Title and category. Only thing that comes up in the database is the ID and title. The category will not show.

Comment: @user3114922 That's not how Stack Overflow works. If you've solved the problem mark the answer that helped you the most as "accepted" (click the hollow tick to the left of the answer. That way you can help future visitors.

Comment: WTH is going on with this question?   Someone's "editing" / hacking this thing all up and it keeps getting rolled back?   Craziness...  LOL

Answer (score 1):

Change `$POST['category'];` to `$_POST['category'];`

```
$category = $POST['category'];
```

should be

```
$category = $_POST['category'];
```